# Distributed Cache in Pig UDF

Tags: apache-pig

Here is my code to Implement a UDF using Distributed Cache Using Pig.

```
public class Regex extends EvalFunc<Integer> {
    static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public List<String> getCacheFiles() {
         Path lookup_file = new Path(
         "hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/top");


        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(1);
        list.add(lookup_file + "#id_lookup");
        return list;
    }

    public void VectorizeData() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("./id_lookup");
        BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while ((line = brd.readLine()) != null) {
            String str[] = line.split("#");
            map.put(str[0], str[1]);
        }
        fr.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Integer exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return map.size();
    }

}
```

Given Below is my Distributed Cache Input File (hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/top)

```
Impetigo|Streptococcus pyogenes#Impetigo
indeterminate leprosy|Uncharacteristic leprosy#indeterminate leprosy
```

Output I get is

```
(0)
(0)
(0)
(0)
(0)
```

This means that my hashmap is empty.
How do i fill my hashmap using Distributed Cache?.

Comment: Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because VectorizeData() was not called in the executable.